# Adding an exisiting project that is already in TFS/Git to a new solution?

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I have a set of "utility" projects that I use across many of my projects. These utility projects are stored in TFS/Git. 
When I start a new project what is the proper way to add those utility projects to the new solution so that they maintain binding to the original source code?

If I were not making any changes to the utility classes I would just reference the dlls somewhere and not add the project but the utility projects will be modified during the new project too.

I have tried adding the project from the local repo in Visual Studio but the Git bindings do not seem to carry thru.

Any suggestions or pointers to an article or two?

Comment: Are your new project being tracked by git too? Try git submodule

Comment: I hope you got good unit tests. Sharing live un-versioned code among many unrelated projects is pretty sketchy. You would have to do a regression test on ALL the applications every time you change something in the shared code to be sure your not creating bugs. If you versioned it and referenced the dll you could at least be sure a specific version of your utilities does indeed work with one of the applications.

Answer (score 0):

If your new project is also tracked by git, this maybe a case where `git submodule` command is the suitable solution.

Take a look at [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).